# drawAsPatternInRect with opacity

Tags: cocoa, uiimage

I am drawing a pattern multiplied on top of a color but I'd also like to adjust the opacity of the pattern image, what would be the best way to do this?

This is what my pattern drawing code looks like:

```
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeMultiply);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"] drawAsPatternInRect:self.bounds];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Have you tried something already? Like using CGContextSetAlpha() inside the GState? Other way would be to manipulate the image to have the necessary alpha, but I think that takes more effort, unless it's going to be reused, in which case it could (maybe?) have a positive effect (assuming the image is stored)

Comment: I haven't tried that but neither `CGContextSetAlpha` nor `CGContextSetFillPattern` seem to work.

Comment: Ah never mind, `CGContextSetAlpha` did work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copying over my comment to make it clear the question is answered.

You can set the alpha for the context with `CGContextSetAlpha()`, other option would be to adjust the alpha of the original image, but if the image is or can be dynamic, then that would probably take more effort to do (it basically falls back to still using `CGContextSetAlpha()` but on another context)